# What regex captures anything between 2 identical characters, but ignoring when those characters are part of a repeated sequence of that character?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

### Problem

I'm trying to look for a pound sign (#) in a string as a start and stop sign for capturing. However, if two or more pound signs occur together (ie: ##), they should be ignored.

Take for example this source string:

```
This## is #a test# for ## some ## # things ## around # here.
```

I expect the regex to find the following:

1. `#a test#`
2. `# things ## around #`

### Best attempt

My best attempt at the regex is:

```
(?!<#)#(?!#)(.+?)(?!<#)#(?!#)
```

but this captures:

1. `# is #`
2. `# for ##`
3. `# #`
4. `# around #`

I thought the negative look behinds `(?!<#)` would prevent using the # character if a previous character in the string was also a pound sign. If I remove them from the regex, the results are exactly the same.

I thought the negative look aheads `(?!#)` would prevent using the # character if the next character in the string was also a pound sign. This part at least seems to work as expected since the 2nd result (`# for ##`) ends with two pound signs, indicating it didn't accept the first pound sign as a terminator.

### Possible solution

I could preprocess the string to convert double pound signs into a unique Unicode character (such as U+2A33: ⨳), but this will throw off a character index in the actual application. I suppose I could double the Unicode character to handle that off-by-one.

But, if I can handle it directly in regex, I can avoid having to preprocess the source string.

### Conclusion

I want to be able to look for a pound sign (#) in a string as a start and stop sign for capturing, unless a pound sign occurs in a string of repeated pound signs. (ie: ##)

Is that possible? If so, was I close? If not, are there other suggestions to the preprocess solution?

Comment: You have a typo, negative lookbehinds are defined as `(?<!...)`, you need to use `(?<!#)#(?!#)(.+?)(?<!#)#(?!#)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh my gosh, that was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Wiktor Stribiżew, I had a typo. The negative look-behind that I used was `(?!<...)`, but that wasn't the right format.

The correct format is: `(?<!...)`

So the correct regex is: `(?<!#)#(?!#)(.+?)(?<!#)#(?!#)`

And I verify it works correctly.

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote it, but questions resolved by fixing a typo are less likely to benefit future readers, so they are often closed.